# Filtering by more than one field in django admin

Tags: django, django-admin

Is it possible to filter results in django's admin interface, by more than one field? For example in the following model

```
class Account(models.model):
    name = model.CharField(max_length=64)

class Row(models.model):
    date = models.DateField()
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account)
```

is it possible to filter the Rows in the admin by both date AND account?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Of course, in your model admin put somethinkg like this:

```
list_filter = ('date', 'account')
```

Comment: Works, yet I think this was not possible in Django prior to 1.3 or 1.4

Comment: yes it's _sorting_ by multiple columns that was introduced with 1.4 - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.4/#multiple-sort-in-admin-interface